# Adding a function call into a 64-bit Visual C++ executable

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, assembly

I have an executable. I want to run it as a process and read live input from its stdout. However, the output is buffered and I can only get it on process exit.

I want to insert a `setbuf(stdout, NULL)` call in the main() method.

I use IDA and I see that C STL functions are imported from MSVCR120.DLL. Function `setbuf()`/`setvbuf()` is not imported, nor `flush()`/`fflush()` is. `LoadLibrary()`/`GetProcAddress()` are not imported.

I'm wondering how to patch the binary so that it does not buffer `stdout`, what can I do? Or maybe I can do something about `MSVCR120.DLL` and make all prints flush?

Comment: A way easier way is to write a replacement for msvcr120.dll that forwards every call to the original dll, but adds a setvbuf at the first IO call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should try to looking into the CRT source to see if there is any configurations that we can use to turn on auto-flush. The source code is available in Visual C++ installation directory (You must also choose to install it too when you install VC).

If there is no configurations to do this. Another way is to hook `vprintf` or anything that you want to flushing after it got called with DLL Injection. You can find a lot of articles about DLL Injection and API Hooking on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Using IDA, I found out that my executable prints using `vprintf()` from `MCVCR120.DLL`.

While `MSVCR.DLL` is a *known dll*, my executable refers `MSVCR120.DLL`, which is not, so I copied `MSVCR120.DLL` from the system directory to the executable's working directory, now the local copy of the DLL is going to be used.

Then I opened the DLL in IDA and found `vprintf()` in exported functions. There were also `flush()` and `_flushall()` exported functions. I decided to use `_flushall()` to flush `stdout` because it needs no arguments and is easy to call (flushes all streams though).

I looked at `vprintf()` assembly code and changed one `call _lock_file` instruction to `call _flushall()` using `Edit > Patch program > Assemble`. I'd better find a better way to insert the call, but at least it doesn't crash now. The executable doesn't write to any files anyway, and it should probably work ok without the `_lock_file()` call.

Now the output is being flushed at every print.